# How to use distributed transactions JTA using plain jdbc

Tags: database, jpa, jdbc, struts2, jta

I have no Idea about JTA,to understand the overall scenarios  please follow this link [How to maintain acid property of 3 sequential transaction of three diffrenet databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269718/how-to-maintain-acid-property-of-3-sequential-transaction-of-three-diffrenet-dat)   ,However based on suggestions from the post,I have to use Distributed transactions. I am using apache-tomcat server.

But As I said i have no idea about JTA, So my problem is that, I have more than 15 database connection, and based on the some condition, their respective database is connected. So I can't create hibernate.cfg.xml and session factories and entities  for each databases .

So My question is that, can i use JTA with plain jdbc? ,and if possible then provide me some links or examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes . You can use JTA with plain JDBC . The general idea is that instead of using JDBC [Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) object to declare the transaction boundary , you use the Transaction Manager object  which is provided by the JTA implementation  to declare  the transaction boundary .

For example , in the case of [Bitronix Transaction Manager](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/NewUserGuide) , declaring a transaction boundary  across many database [Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html)  can be done by the following codes:

```
        PoolingDataSource derbyDataSource1 = new PoolingDataSource();
        derbyDataSource1.setClassName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedXADataSource");
        derbyDataSource1.setUniqueName("derby1");  
        derbyDataSource1.getDriverProperties().setProperty("databaseName", "database1");
        derbyDataSource1.init();

        PoolingDataSource derbyDataSource2= new PoolingDataSource();
        derbyDataSource2.setClassName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedXADataSource");
        derbyDataSource2.setUniqueName("derby2");
        derbyDataSource2.getDriverProperties().setProperty("databaseName", "database2");
        derbyDataSource2.init();

        BitronixTransactionManager btm = TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager();

        btm.begin();
        try {
            Connection c1= derbyDataSource1.getConnection();
            Connection c2= derbyDataSource2.getConnection();

            /***Use c1 and c2 to execute statements again their corresponding DBs as usual**/


            btm.commit();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            btm.rollback();
        }
```

Comment: ok, have seen this my recent post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269718/how-to-maintain-acid-property-of-3-sequential-transaction-of-three-diffrenet-dat, is your example works well with distributed database.

Comment: and also can I use JTA instead of BitronixTransactionManager or BitronixTransactionManager  is a better option

Comment: Hi arvin,BitronixTransactionManager is one of the implementation of  JTA .